# Using pytesseract.image_to_string makes the frame capture stream very laggy

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using this tutorial [Optical Character Recognition Using Raspberry Pi With OpenCV and Tesseract](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/tutorial/optical-character-recognizer-using-raspberry-pi-with-opencv-and-tesseract)  to detect text using the Raspberry Pi 4. However, I want it to continuously detect the image and output a string for the text that it detects. This in turn makes the raspberry Pi 4 capture stream very laggy. The issue is mainly from this line in the code "imageToString = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)" and I would like to know if there's a way of improving the video stream without changing the functionality of the code.

```
import pytesseract
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera

camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640, 480)
camera.framerate = 30

rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640, 480))

for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr", use_video_port=True):
    image = frame.array
    cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
    rawCapture.truncate(0)

    imageToString = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)

    if key == ord("s"):
        text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image)
        print(text)
        cv2.imshow("Frame", image)
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of tesseract do you use? Can you also provide some input images used for OCR?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have the latest one installed basically. Input images? It's basically capturing images frame by frame.